# Best way to illustrate how much code re factoring has occurred in SVN

Tags: svn, metrics

On one project we have been working on recently, we have in essence totally re-factored the entire code base, touching almost all (if not all code files), one thing that I would like to get a view of, is exactly how many files have been altered from one revision to another.

i.e over the span of 3 months I am interested in how many files have been worked on, how many commits etc.

Ideally this would be some kind of nice report out of SVN but I am not sure this is possible?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/).

It's a free, open-source tool.  We've been using it for a long time and the amount of data, charts, tables, etc. that it provides is extremely impressive.

Comment: This fitted the bill exactly. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

you can try [Programeter](http://programeter.com/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.